# MongoInternalException: DBPort.findOne failed while running on GAE localserver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, mlab

I am trying to connect to remote MongoDB (mongolab) from my local GAE server (localhost/8888). I am using morphia and my mongodb driver version is 2.4. My code looks like this:

Mongo m = new Mongo("xyz.mongolab.com",);

Datastore datastore = new Morphia().createDatastore(m, "staging","uname","password".toCharArray());

This throws the following exception :

com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: DBPort.findOne failed
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.findOne(DBPort.java:153)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.runCommand(DBPort.java:159)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.testMaster(DBTCPConnector.java:371)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.(Mongo.java:167)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [xyz.mongolab.com/:] bc:java.net.SocketException: Operation failure: setSocketOptions: Not yet implemented
    at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:205)

Does somebody know why this is happening ?

Comment: java driver version 2.4? this is pretty old .. have you tried to use a newer version?

Comment: Guess that was the problem. But tried 2.10.1 and now I am facing this problem :

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)
 at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:376)
 at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:549)
 at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)

Comment: Do you have authentication enabled on that server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a problem with using the old mongodb driver.. works after i upgraded..